# CaptainCasa framework: Long polling Invoke ActionListener stops getting called

Tags: jsp, captaincasa

I have long-polling setup in a pagebean as such:

```
<t:beanprocessing id="g_1" beanbinding="#{d.SomeImportantPageGridUI}" >
<t:sessioncloser id="g_7" />
<t:longpolling id="g_5" actionListener="#{d.SomeImportantPageGridUI.onLongPollingAction}" duration="#{d.SomeImportantPageGridUI.refreshInterval}" longpollingurl="#{d.SomeImportantPageGridUI.longPollingURL}" rendered="#{d.SomeImportantPageGridUI.longPollingRendered}" />
</t:beanprocessing>
```

SomeImportantPageGridUI is a PageBean embedded in a WorkpageDispatchedPageBean using rowpagebeaninclude. The parent bean is dispatched from the main workplace.

When i switch to another page in the workplace, and then switch back to the parent "SomeImportantPage", #{d.SomeImportantPageGridUI.onLongPollingAction} stops getting invoked.

When i checked the browser devtools network tab, the long polling and ccaround requests continue as usual and i can't see a before-after difference.

ccaround continue to have the proper invoke param:

```
j_id_jsp_359873986_1%3Accoutestpage%3A_I_0SRI0-_I_220-g_22-g_5.action=invoke()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a buggy behavior of the LONGPOLLING component. Thanks for telling us!

We could reproduce and fix the bug. The solution is part of next update, which is scheduled for Monday, July 26th. Update number will be CC 20210726.

In case you require some interim update, please let us know.